# phpmyadmin Cannot connect: invalid settings on mac after changing permsion setting in Xammp files to read and write for admin

Tags: php, macos, phpmyadmin, xampp, file-permissions

I know this question has been asked before, but all the answers did not solve my error,

Recently my **phpmyadmin** was working fine until when i changed the file **permission of Xammp files** in my application folder.
I gave **read and write  permission to the admin user** to all the files in Xammp file .

I tried **reverting the permission** but i still get this error .
Thank you....

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that you don't change the database user also?

Comment: This is very weird....can you check the database log file with a `tail -f`

Comment: @Hackerman i did not change anything in the database  ,how do i check the database log file

Comment: For example, on Linux you can check the log with a command like `tail -f /var/log/mysql.log` ...the problem is that you are using mac, so, the log should be on another directory